# segment_separators option not being applied

Tags: routes, symfony1

I am using symfony 1.4, and I have a form with some POST params that have dots ('.') in them. These are being translated to underscores '_' before reaching the action code. To alleviate this, I have made the following route:

```
configure_submit:
  url:        /configure/submitconfig
  options:    { segment_separators: ['/'] }
  params:     { module: configure, action: submitconfig }
```

And it seems to be triggered by the code, because the logs indicate:

> Feb 17 14:55:52 symfony [info] {sfPatternRouting} Match route "configure_submit"
>   (/configure/submitconfig) for /configure/submitconfig with parameters 
>   array (  'module' => 'configure',  'action' => 'submitconfig',)

However, the parameter comes through without periods anyway.

What can I do about the route so that the segment_separators option is applied?

Comment: There aren't any parameters in your route? What are you trying to match?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the segment separators on `factories.yml`

```
all:
  routing:
    class: sfPatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
     segment_separators: [/,-,.]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `segment_separators` parameter configures *route* segment separators, so you can have urls like `/:param1.:param2`. It has nothing to do with post parameters, or anything besides routing.